# Protobuf-net object reference after deserialization not equal although AsReferenceDefault used

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to use profobuf-net, but although it seems to support "object by reference" starting from version 2 according to documentation (I'm testing with version 2.0.0.668), I don't get it to work.

To make the problem easy understandable, here is a short example code showing it:

```
private static void Test()
{
    MainObject mainObject = new MainObject();
    TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
    ObjectByReference objectByReference = new ObjectByReference();

    mainObject.TestObjects.Add(testObject);
    mainObject.ObjectByReferences.Add(objectByReference);

    testObject.ObjectByReference = objectByReference;

    // Make sure the reference is the same before serialization.
    Debug.Assert(testObject.ObjectByReference == objectByReference);

    byte[] buf;
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, mainObject);
        buf = ms.ToArray();
    }

    // --> Deserialize.
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buf))
    {
        mainObject = Serializer.Deserialize<MainObject>(ms);
    }

    testObject = mainObject.TestObjects[0];
    objectByReference = mainObject.ObjectByReferences[0];

    // Fails as now the reference suddenly is not the same anymore!
    Debug.Assert(testObject.ObjectByReference == objectByReference);
}

[ProtoContract]
class MainObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<TestObject> TestObjects = new List<TestObject>();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<ObjectByReference> ObjectByReferences = new List<ObjectByReference>();
}

[ProtoContract]
class TestObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ObjectByReference ObjectByReference { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
class ObjectByReference
{
}
```

As you can see I'm using the `AsReferenceDefault = true` attribute for the class `ObjectByReference`, but this seems not to have any effect:
the test still fails in the last line of the `Test` function as the two objects are no longer reference equal after deserialization.

Why is that the case?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I'm really stucked with this issue. I also posted it as bug here: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/116, but did not get any reply yet. Doesn't anybode else has this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark your field as (AsReference = true)

Example:

```
[ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
 public MyClas className;

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
public class MyClass
{

}
```